# Static initializers and final constants in Java

Tags: java, static, final, static-block, static-initializer

Given the following simple code in Java.

```
final class Demo
{
    public static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    static
    {
        System.out.println("Static constructor invoked.");
    }
}

public final class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.out.println(Demo.serialVersionUID);
    }
}
```

In this simplest of Java code, the `static` constructor is expected to be invoked, when the class `Demo` is initialized through the `main()` method through `Demo.serialVersionUID` but it **does not**.

If this program were run without modifications, the output would only be `1` (the message - *Static constructor invoked.* as specified in the `static` block would not be displayed).

---

If we want the message to be printed as specified in the `static` initializer then, we need to modify the declaration statement in the `Demo` class,

```
public static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
```

to either,

```
public static long serialVersionUID=1L;
```

removing the `final` modifier or,

```
public static final Long serialVersionUID=1L;
```

changing the primitive type `long` to its corresponding wrapper type `Long`.

So, why does it behave this way? Why does it not display the message in the `static` constructor without the specified changes to the program?

Comment: I mainly wanted to know the reason why `long` (primitive) needs to be modified to `Long` (wrapper) to display that message.

Comment: One of the requirements for a field to be a compiletime constant is that it must be either a primitive or a string.

Comment: Marko Topolnik provided an excellent answer to exactly that question on the question I linked. It boils down to `static final` primitives or `String`s being compile-time constants, so their values get hardcoded into where they're referenced, rather than actually being referenced - which avoids the need to actually load the class.